# TextBox size change when re-sizing the form

Tags: c#, forms, resize

Many programs re-size their text boxes, labels, picture boxes, etc... when you change the the whole form's size. But when I drag a text box in my form and make the form smaller, it will overlap the text box and it'll be unusefull because I can't see everything which is written in there.

It's hard to explain so here are some photo's:

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check the property [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) for your textbox.
It appears that you need to set to `Top, Left, Right`

If you set in this way, the textbox remains anchored to its container left, top and right borders.
Thus, when the form (the container) is resized, the textbox *automatically* grows or shrinks to maintain the original distance set in the designer.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @Demodave it will be more easy and efficient if you experiment a bit using a control and changing the values of that property.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Click Dock dropdown menu and select desired location]

Click Dock dropdown menu and select desired location

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, the textbox will re-size automatically